# Howto specify name of executable with Delphi and MSBuild?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration, delphi-xe2

I want to use the same Delphi project to generate two executables (with a different set of conditional defines). How can I specify the name of the generated executable with msbuild?

Let's say the project is called `Foo.dproj`. The first executable should be called `Foo.exe` (the default), the second one should be called `Foo-2.exe`.

Comment: Use the IDE to change the output name. Then look at the change in the .dproj file. Now you know the name of the property, you can set it with /pNAME=VALUE on the msbuild command line

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi David, to be honest, I couldn't find any option to do this in the IDE (only the output directory, executable name seems to always equal the project name).

Comment: If that is so, the you need your build script to do the rename for you.

Answer (score 3):

One trivial solution would be the following build script:

```
msbuild ... // Build second executuable
move Bin\Foo.exe Bin\Foo-2.exe
msbuild ... // Build first executable
```

Comment: @jachguate Why? On *nix the command is `mv`. Move and rename are the same thing.

Comment: I just don't remember what I was thinking when I posted the comment, but you're right @David.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a whole lot of documentation on the details of setting Delphi options using msbuild. The procedure I follow is as follows:

1. Find the setting you wish to control in the IDE.
2. Make a change to that setting and observe how that change is effected in the .dproj file.
3. Hopefully you will now have the name of a property that can be set by passing the `/p` argument to msbuild, i.e. `/pNAME=VALUE`.

In the case of the output file name, to the very best of my knowledge, there is no option in the IDE or .dproj file, or even to `dcc32.exe`, that allows you to control the output file name. Which means that your only option is to do the renaming as part of your build script.